# Starting built in Apache server in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: apache, webserver, osx-mavericks

I'd like to start my apache server in my Mac OSX Mavericks. Here is what I did:

1. launch the terminal application
2. sudo apachectl start
3. The server started without problem. But I got the following problem when I tried to open the localhost in web browser:

> You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Here is my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf: (I didn't change anything here)

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all </Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

Can anybody advise what could be the cause ? Thanks

Comment: http://superuser.com is probably a good place to post this. It's definitely off-topic for stackoverflow.com though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Stack overflow is not the place to ask any question regarding with IT technologies?

Comment: I added to superuser.com already. But do I need to remove it here?

Comment: No need to remove it from here; it'll either be deleted or put on hold/closed or neither, depending on who sees the post. No, IT technologies aren't appropriate at this particular site in the stack overflow network, this site is for programming topics (generally code related, but not tool configuration related). At the bottom of the page you'll find a list of links to several of the more popular sites in the network; each has an about page to tell you what types of questions are supported at their particular site.

Comment: One of the things I love about stack overflow is when I'm trying to do `x`. And then I find someone saying, "I'm trying to do `x`, so I tried these things." And then following those steps solves my problem, without even looking at the answers to their question. So thanks for `sudo apachectl start`!

Comment: The question was moved to http://superuser.com/questions/676944/starting-built-in-apache-server-in-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, point to a file you know is present. By default there is no index.html or similar file (it produces the "It Works!" page from index.html.en

```
ls /Library/WebServer/Documents
PoweredByMacOSX.gif
PoweredByMacOSXLarge.gif
index.html.en
```

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/PoweredByMacOSX.gif

Next, try repairing permissions. If that doesn't work:

```
sudo chown -R root.wheel /Library/WebServer/Documents
sudo chmod -R a+rX /Library/WebServer/Documents
```

When in doubt:

```
sudo tail /var/log/apache2/error_log
```

Answer (score 15):

Easy way to start apanche server in mavrick

execute this command

```
sudo apachectl start

sudo apachectl stop

sudo apachectl restart
```